# Отображение маркеров вдоль маршрута

Tags: api, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, карты

Если я в яндекс навигаторе построю маршрут из пункта А в пункт, то я могу выбрать объекты, которые нужно отображать на маршруте (например, кафешки или заправки). То есть отображается линия маршрута и маркеры объектов по маршруту.

Разрабатываем свое мобильное приложение, используем ЯндексКарты. В приложении пользователи могут ставить "метки интереса" (например, достопримечательности). Как реализовать отображение меток на маршруте? Есть ли готовый алгоритм в API карт (гуглил, но не нашел), или придется писать свой алгоритм фильтрации маркеров?

Answer (score 0):

Встроенной возможности JS API Яндекс Карт по построению на определённом расстоянии от линии (маршрута) опоясывающего её полигона нет. Если собрать свой метод и генерировать подходящий полигон, [geoQuery](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geoQuery.html) Яндекса позволить проводить выборку из вашего набора объектов.